# ios alarm clock app rejection with AppStore review guidelines 2.16

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, info.plist

My alarm clock app was received an rejection from app review process:

> 2.16: Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion,
>   local notifications, etc.
>
> 2.16
>
> We found that your app uses a background mode but does not include
>   functionality that requires that mode to run persistently. This
>   behavior is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> We noticed your app declares support for audio in the
>   UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but did not include features
>   that require persistent audio.
>
> As indicated in the iOS Application Programming Guide:
>
> "This key is intended for use by applications that provide audible
>   content to the user while in the background, such as music-player or
>   streaming-audio applications."
>
> Therefore, it would be appropriate to provide audible content to the
>   user while the app is in the background or remove the "audio" setting
>   from the UIBackgroundModes key.
>
> For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple
>   Developer Technical Support. Please be sure to:
>
> - include the complete details of your rejection issues
> - prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see
>   Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application
>   Crash Reports.
>
> If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the
>   workflow as described in
>   with Xcode's Archive feature".

I have sent an mail to notice I need background mode to play alarm when it is alerting and user press "home" button that makes app into background. And then I got an reply:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting us to provide additional information about
>   your app Kill Ants (alarm clock). I have added this information to
>   your app record.
>
> In the future, you can add this information directly to your app
>   record by including this information in the Review Notes of your app
>   or by replying in the Resolution Center when your app is in the
>   Rejected state. When you provide information in either of these ways,
>   it is not necessary to also provide the information by email or
>   through the Contact Us form.
>
> You can find more information about "Editing and Updating App
>   Information" in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide here:
>
> When the Resolution Center or Review Notes are no longer in the
>   editable states referenced in the Guide, you can continue
>   communications through iTunes Connect Contact Us using the steps
>   below:
>
> 1. Go to
> 2. Select 'App Review'
> 3. Select 'Continuing Communications', then add your information or questions.
>
> I hope this information is helpful.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> App Review Team

How do I handle this problem? I app actually needs the backgroundMode to play alarm music in background. Anyone has the same problem? How do you solve it?

Comment: You don't need this background mode.  With a notification, you can choose a sound to be played when it is fired.  The audio background mode is only for **continuous** background audio.

Comment: It sounds like you should resubmit your app with the explanation added. The second block you quote, the email, isn't about your app. It's just telling you it wasn't necessary to send the email and that you could have added it directly to your app submission in iTunesConnect. They're not saying your reason is invalid. No one on the review team has taken a second look at your app with that added explanation.  They may still reject it, but they'll tell you why your stated reason isn't approved if they do.

Comment: @borrrden My app is an alarm type app. I need make alarm music play smoothly when user let app into background and continue play this alarm music in background. If I use local notification, alarm music will be stopped and started again via local notification.

Comment: That doesn't sound at all like an "alarm" to me.  Why does an alarm need to continuously make sound?  Regardless, as Bill said, no one has looked at your explanation yet.

Comment: How did this turn out in the end? Did Apple approve your app?

Comment: I think @ParagonLight is using something like https://github.com/mruegenberg/MMPDeepSleepPreventer. It prevents the app going to "inactive" mode, which kills all the NSTimers. If you want a sound of more than 30 seconds to be played as an alarm (very logical), you can´t use Local Notifications.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?